# Batch - Copy Certain Lines of data from one text File to certain liens in another pre-made text file

Tags: batch-file

Been struggling to create a batch file that can extract certain lines of text from one text file and then paste that extracted data into another text file.
The lines taken from will always be the same and the lines that they will be pasted too will also always be the same.
I have been looking around and managed to get part of it working but as I am looking to use a text file for the formatting of the output, I cannot work out how to paste the data at the end of the pre generated line can any one help?

So far I have the following code, which isn't working-

```
   @Echo ON
    setlocal enableextensions
    set me=%~n0
    set parent=%~dp0
    set varhome=inputvariables.txt
    set formathome=formatofvariables.txt
    set outputfile=output.txt
    set locationname=SITENAME
    set /a i=1
    for /F %%o IN (%varhome%) DO (
        set "line!i!=%%o"
        set /a i=!i!+1
    )
    set /a k=1
    for /F %%l IN (%formathome%) DO (
        set "line!k!=%%l"
        set /a k=!k!+1
    )
    echo %locationname% - >output.txt
    echo %formathome2% - %line2%>>output.txt
    echo %formathome7% - %line7%>>output.txt
    echo %formathome15% - %line15%>>output.txt
    echo %formathome16% - %line16%>>output.txt

pause
```

## File contents

inputvariables.txt (this file contains raw data with no headings or context, most variables are not currently used, but may in the future, each variable on its own line.)

variable1

variable2

variable3

variable4

variable5

variable6

variable7

variable8

variable9

variable10

etc....

formatofvariables.txt (this file contains the headings for the raw data which I would liek to use but the lines are all out of order and only some of the data is used)

heading1 - this is the heading taken from sitename var set by user above

-blank line-

heading2 - this is the heading for variable 2 from file -inputvariables.txt

-blank line-

heading3 - this is the heading for variable 15 from file -inputvariables.txt

-blank line-

heading4 - this is the heading for variable 16 from file -inputvariables.txt

-blank line-

heading5 - this is the heading for variable 7 from file -inputvariables.txt

output.txt (this file is the combination of the heading, then the variable data, put to the correct lines advised above)

Comment: You haven't provided a description of what you intend to have appear in `output.txt`. Please provide examples. Does `output` contain the lines from `format` with lines (2,7,15,16) replaced / appended with line (?) from `variable` or what??

Comment: Thanks, updated to be more clear!

Was looking to use the FileFormat.txt as a base then just paste the intended data from the VariableFile.txt on the end of that line, but it just replaces the line with the previous scripts I have made.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this fragment:

```
seti=1
for /F %%l IN (%varhome%) DO (
 set line!i!=%%l
 set /a i=!i!+1
)
```

OK - there's a syntax error on the first of these lines. "should" be `set i=1`

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. `set /a` doesn't need quotes.

So, `set /a i=1` and `set "line!i!=%%l"`

This takes each line from the file `%varhome%` and creates variables `line1 line2 line...` containing each successive line.

Now if you were to repeat this operation for the other file, `%formathome%` and put it into a different  set of variables by changing `line` to say, `format` then you'd have *that* file's contents in `format1 format2 format...`

Having obtained that data, now decide what you want to write out.

If it's just the 4 lines you indicate then you need to

```
echo %format2% - %line2%
echo %format7% - %line7%
```

etc.

This would show the result in the window.

To output that data to a file, you need

```
echo %format2% - %line2%>OutputFile.txt
echo %format7% - %line7%>>OutputFile.txt
echo %format15% - %line15%>>OutputFile.txt
```

Note : The `>` is not preceded by a space. If you put a space there, then the line will acquire a terminal space in the file, which can be difficult to detect.

Note also: The first line has ONE `>`. This creates a new file. The remainder of your output lines have TWO `>` characters, which append the data to the file.

A far more convenient form is

```
(
 echo %format2% - %line2%
 echo %format7% - %line7% 
 echo %format15% - %line15%
)>OutputFile.txt
```

where all of the `echo` commands' outputs in the "code block" (parenthesised sequence of commands) are accumulated to the file

Depending on what your output data requirements actually are (sorry, still unclear), other strategies might be employed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I seem to have completely broken it now - new code appended in the original comment.

Comment: Your loop on `%%i` sets variables named `line1` etc. Perhaps if you were to set variables named `formathome1` etc. with `%%o` then you wouldn't be overwriting the variables `line?` that you've just established.  And `setme=%~n0` needs a space after the `t`.

Comment: Empty lines are ignored by `for/f`. This can be overcome, or you could adjust your "subscript" numbers to suit

Comment: Again, thanks for all your help, especially being so quick, but unfortunately, changing those loop variables doesn't seem to work, still trying to figure out what its doing, it keeps advising "Missing operator" when I add PAUSE to the end to diagnose it, this seems to be happening for both the varhome and format home loops and on every line!

*updated code to my latest revision*

Comment: You need `setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion`. By default, extensions are enabled and delayedexpansion disabled. With `delayedexpansion` disabled, `!i!`  is resolved to `!i!`, so batch sees `set /a i=!i!+1`, literally, hence the error message.With `delayedexpansion` enabled, `!i!`  is resolved to `[the current value of i]`, so batch sees `set /a i=[the current value of i]+1`. Another way this can be achieved is `set /a i+=1`, but you still need `delayedexpansion` in order to have `line!i!` interpreted as `line1`...

Comment: When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will close if a syntax-error is found or the script runs to completion. You *can* put a `pause` after statements and home in on the error, but better to [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any (error) messages will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, I have been testing with some other methods of running 2 For loops side by side but have had no joy unfortunately, I have got further with the code researching for loops but the script now just seems to capture the last variable processed as below:

Comment: C:\Scripts\TEST>(
set "formathome1=Variable4"
 set /a formatcount=1+1
)

C:\Scripts\TEST>(
set "formathome1=Variable5)"
 set /a formatcount=1+1
)

C:\Scripts\TEST>echo Variable 5 - SITENAME 1>Output.txt

C:\Scripts\TEST>(>echo  -  1>>Output.txt

C:\Scripts\TEST9>echo  -  1>>Output.txt

C:\Scripts\TEST>echo  -  1>>Output.txt

C:\Scripts\TEST>echo  -  1>>Output.txt

C:\Scripts\TEST>pause
Press any key to continue . . .